# How to return the local value of a function to my global list?

Tags: python, list, function

I am writing a def function that will take in input to a list. First, it will detect if there is the same value in that list, if yes, it will put it to another list, if no, it will put it in the first list. The code is something like this:

```
uniqueList = []
leftover = []
def addToList(number):
    if any(uniqueList.count(number) > 0 for number in UniqueList):
        leftover.append(number)
        return leftover
    else:
        uniqueList.append(number)
        return uniqueList
```

The problem is when I run it, the number input doesn’t seem to be saved to the list, for example, the first input is '20', then the output is [20] for the uniqueList and [ ] for leftover. But when I input '20' again, the output is still [20] for the uniqueList and [ ] for leftover. Why is this happening?

Comment: pass the list to the function and return a copy of the updated list, or update it inplace and return nothing. The last thing you want a function to do is create side effects.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "the output is still [20] for the uniqueList and [ ] for leftover."  This function only returns one thing -- it can't have two outputs.

Comment: This seems to work. If I input 5, it's put into `uniqueList`. If I input 5 again, it's put into `leftoverList`.

Comment: Also, `if any(uniqueList.count(number) > 0 for number in UniqueList)` seems like just a complicated way of saying `if number in uniqueList`

Comment: as an aside, `uniqueList.count(number) > 0` should just be `number in UniqueList`

Comment: @Carcigenicate You are right about the global mutable, varible do not need the global keyword unless it need to be reassigned.

Comment: @JohnGordon To me it looks more like a complicated way of saying `if uniqueList`.

Comment: What's `UniqueList`, and how does it differ from `uniqueList`?

Comment: @JohnGordon I print out both lists out at the end, sorry if I didn’t state it out clearly.

Comment: @Carcigenicate The function only works properly for me is when I put for instance '5' into the uniqueList in advance, then do 'addToList(5)'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`return leftover` and `return uniqueList` don't copy but return reference to list, so if contents of list changes, value changes in to where refer. Then, to return such lists to use `copy` module.

```
import copy

uniqueList = []
leftover = []
def addToList(number):
    if any(uniqueList.count(number) > 0 for number in UniqueList):
        leftover.append(number)
        return copy.copy(leftover)
    else:
        uniqueList.append(number)
        return copy.copy(uniqueList)
```

But, this is [shallow copy](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/copy-python-deep-copy-shallow-copy/), if you want to copy nested object, use `deepcopy` instead.

Comment: I did what you have suggested, but when I print out both list at the end, it still has the same problem. Almost as if the reset itself every time I run it.

Comment: You're going to need to give more detail, ideally a full [mcve], because alone, the code you have won't produce the behavior you're describing.